# Anyone else sending email from a Django app with a celery task, using Amazon-SES, hosted on Heroku?

Tags: django, heroku, django-celery, amazon-ses

I know this works, because I have django-registrations app sending activation emails.  But I'm having no luck re-creating this functionality for another app.  In views.py, in the add_article function, I execute the celery task send_published_article.delay(request.user.email, subject, body), and this works locally. But when I deploy to Heroku, no emails get sent when I set is_published to true.  No Error gets generated, so I'm not sure where to start looking.

Heroku logs show this for the failed attempt at emailing POST: 2013-04-30T20:57:55.650246+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path=/story/add/article host=secure-brook-2084.herokuapp.com fwd="108.167.16.106" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=265ms status=302 bytes=5

tasks.py

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from celery import task
from apps.profiles.models import Client

@task(name='send-email')
def send_published_article(sender, subject, body):
    for client in Client.objects.all():
        recipient = client.email
        send_mail(subject, body, sender, [recipient], fail_silently=False)
```

views.py

```
import os
import redis
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib import messages
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render_to_response
from django.template import RequestContext
from models import Article
from forms import ArticleForm
from story.tasks import send_published_article

@login_required 
def add_article(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ArticleForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            article = form.save(commit=False)
            article.author = request.user
            article.save()
            msg = "Article saved successfully"
            messages.success(request, msg, fail_silently=True)
            if article.is_published:
                subject = article.title
                body = article.text
                send_published_article.delay(request.user.email, subject, body)
                msg = "Article saved and published successfully"
                messages.success(request, msg, fail_silently=True)
            return redirect(article)
    else:
        form = ArticleForm()
    return render_to_response('story/article_form.html', 
                              { 'form': form },
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I've got the settings stuff set up like so in my settings.production:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django_ses.SESBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'ME <my.email@email.com>'
```

If you need more information, or have an idea on a test to help find the bug, let me know.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution to this problem is so simple it makes me want to cry.  I didn't have the celeryd and celerybeat dynos enabled in my Heroku app.  Turned 'em on, applied changed, and boom, emails.